# Recalling an Int from a method?

Tags: java, random

I need to return an int I made using 4 random distinct digits (none repeated) to the main method so that I can use it for the rest of my work. I cannot use string methods either. I want it to print the random number

This is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      int generateSecretNumber;
      System.out.print("Random number is: "+generateSecretNumber);

}

public static int generateSecretNumber(int w, int x, int y, int z, int secretNumber) {
    Random ran = new Random();

    w = ran.nextInt();
    x = ran.nextInt();
    y = ran.nextInt();
    z = ran.nextInt();


    while (w == x || w == y || w == z){
    w = ran.nextInt();
    }
    while (x == w || x == y || x==z){
    x = ran.nextInt();
    }
    while (y == w || y == x || y == z){
    y = ran.nextInt();
    }
    while (z == w|| z== x || z == y){
    z = ran.nextInt();
    }

    if (w != x && x != y && y!=z){

    secretNumber = w + x + y + z;
    }

    return secretNumber;
}

}
```

Comment: What's your current issue?

Comment: Actually call the method first, you may not even need to store it in a local.

Comment: How do i do that?? I want the secretNumber to be printed from the main method.

Comment: you have same name for variable and function which is wrong. Change name of variable to secretNumber, then call the function and assign return value of generateSecretNumber to secretNumber like secretNumber=generateSecretNumber(give aruguments here);

Comment: Can you please show me on code? I am having a hard time understanding?

Comment: You should look at my response again, I added an explanation for everything, and I made the loop much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are never actually calling your `generateSecretNumber()` method, you'r declaring a variable instead. Remove the declaration in your main, and change the printing line to `System.out.print("Random number is: " + generateSecretNumber());`.

Next, the `generateSecretNumber()` method should not have any arguments, since it determines what it's going to do entirely by itself, and doesn't require any outside data. Since the arguments are gone, you also need to declare `int w, x, y, z;` at the beginning of it.

Secondly, you're generating a random integer without an upper bound. This is not at all what you'd want, instead, your upper bound for the `rand.nextInt()` calls should be 10, resulting in `rand.nextInt(10)`. This will pick a random integer anywhere from 0 to 9.

And finally, you're returning the sum of the digits rather than the actual four-digit number that they'd make. Instead, return the sum of each of the digits times their place. For example, the fourth digit should be `w * 1000`.

Resulting code example:

```
public class RandUniqueFourDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Random number is: " + generateSecretNumber());
    }

    public static int generateSecretNumber() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int w = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

        // Generate each digit until they're all unique
        while(w == x || w == y || w == z || x == y || x == z || y == z) {
            w = rand.nextInt(10);
            x = rand.nextInt(10);
            y = rand.nextInt(10);
            z = rand.nextInt(10);
        }

        // Generate each digit until they're all unique
        w = rand.nextInt(10);
        do x = rand.nextInt(10); while(x == w)

        // Combine them into one integer and return
        return w * 1000 + x * 100 + y * 10 + z;
    }
}
```

And for a more efficient loop (each number is only re-generated when it needs to be, like your initial code), replace the while loop completely with this:

```
w = rand.nextInt(10);
do x = rand.nextInt(10); while(x == w);
do y = rand.nextInt(10); while(y == w || y == x);
do z = rand.nextInt(10); while(z == w || z == x || z == y);
```

Resulting in:

```
public class RandUniqueFourDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateSecretNumber());
    }

    public static int generateSecretNumber() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int w = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

        // Generate each digit until they're all unique
        w = rand.nextInt(10);
        do x = rand.nextInt(10); while(x == w);
        do y = rand.nextInt(10); while(y == w || y == x);
        do z = rand.nextInt(10); while(z == w || z == x || z == y);

        // Combine them into one integer and return
        return w * 1000 + x * 100 + y * 10 + z;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering there aren't many numbers you could compute all of them in memory and return back a random value from it.

```
public class RandomGenerator {
    private static final List<Integer> numbers;
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    static {
        for(int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) {
            int x = i%10;
            int y = (i/10)%10;
            int z = (i/100)%100;
            int u = (i/1000);

            // Check for uniqueness
            if(unique) { numbers.add(i); }
        }
    }

    public static Integer getNumber() {
        return numbers.get(random.nextInt(numbers.size()));
    }
}
```